# leave vim split window in insert mode

Tags: bash, vim

I want to view the output of a bash command in a vim split window `:split`. To this end I installed "Conque Shell" which displays bash in a split window upon `:ConqueTermSplit bash`. I can then run my shell command and watch the output in insert mode. However, to return to the other window I need to type <CTRL-W> <Up> in command mode, so I need to leave insert mode. Hence the display of the command output freezes and continues only if I return to this window and enter insert mode. So how can I leave "Conque Shell" without leaving insert mode.

Note that other ways of viewing the bash output in a second window might solve my problem as well. However it should update while I am working in the other window and allow me to signal e.g. <CTRL-C> to the application.

---

The ConqueTerm documentation says:

3.1.5 Keep updating terminal buffer                 *ConqueTerm_ReadUnfocused*

If set to 1 then your Conque buffers will continue to update after you've
switched to another buffer.

Note: Conque buffers may continue to update, but they will not scroll down as
new lines are added beyond the bottom of the visible buffer area. This is a
limitation of the Vim scripting language for which I haven't found a
workaround.
>
    let g:ConqueTerm_ReadUnfocused = 1

Comment: Do you have mouse input enabled?  If so, you can just click in the other window.  Otherwise, we'll have to make a `:inoremap` command.

Comment: No mouse input!!! Is it obvious how to do the <code>:inoremap</code> command?

Comment: The ConqueTerm documentation says

Comment: With mouse input the ConqueTerm leaves input mode as well if I work in the other window...

Comment: Interesting question. I am using ConqueTerm without mouse input capability and was wondering about this exact problem as well!

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK Vim has no support for asynchronous sessions, so this is more of a response to your request for potential alternative options.

The way that I currently get around this issue is by using [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net), which is described as:

> a terminal multiplexer: it enables a number of terminals (or windows),
>   each running a separate program, to be created, accessed, and
>   controlled from a single screen.

So, basically, instead of splitting your screen in Vim you would split it using tmux, and then in one window run Vim and in the other run whatever other program you want which will update completely independently of Vim. And just like Vim you can switch between the windows (or panes as they are called in tmux lingo) using a couple of key strokes.

There is another terminal multiplexer available called [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), which is also quite popular. And the reason I mention that is because I like to have options, and also there are two plugins for Vim that allow you to send output directly to an attached screen or tmux session. For GNU screen, [slime.vim](http://technotales.wordpress.com/2007/10/03/like-slime-for-vim/), and for tmux, [tslime.vim](https://github.com/kikijump/tslime.vim).

Answer (score 0):

Using `VIM` and `ConqueTerm` you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>UP</kbd> / <kbd>Down</kbd> to change windows in `split` mode.

Just click on <kbd>ESC</kbd> first to exit the `insert` mode.

It works well on my side.

Comment: The question is "So how can I leave "Conque Shell" without leaving insert mode."