# VIM Conque with GHCI --- Arrow keys don't work

Tags: bash, vim, ghc, ghci, vim-plugin

I tried searching, but couldn't find an answer.

I have the Conque VIM extension installed in order to have a shell open on the bottom half of my VIM window. https://code.google.com/p/conque/

Launching bash via Conque allows the arrow keys to work fine. I launched by using:

```
ConqueTermSplit bash
```

However, when launching GHCI, the arrow keys don't work. Instead it prints two characters, such as **0A** or **0B**. I launched GHCI using the following command:

```
ConqueTermSplit ghci
```

Finally, when launching ghci normally from bash (without using Conque from VIM), the arrow keys work fine.

Using gnome-vim with the latest version of Conque and GHCI version 7.8.3.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT:** After looking at two other questions on StackOverFlow about Conque, it seems that it would be easier to use Screen or something similar instead than solving this. If anyone finds a solution then please post it.

Two questions mentioned (**this is not a duplicate**):

[leave vim split window in insert mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018774/leave-vim-split-window-in-insert-mode)

[vim integration with ghci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546959/vim-integration-with-ghci)

Comment: I guess this is `libedit` vs `libreadline` problem..

Comment: @J-16SDiZ hmm, so how should I go on about this? Is there another version of the lib that I can use? Is there a next step? I did have to install libgmp3-dev from the Ubuntu repo in order for GHCI to work. Could that version of libgmp be the issue, or is it something that Conque uses (which is what I am suspecting)?